# Append slice to slice of slices

Tags: go, append, slice

I have data structure:

```
type PosList []int

type InvertedIndex struct {
  Capacity  int
  Len       int
  IndexList []PosList
}
```

I have problem with Add method:

```
func (ii *InvertedIndex) Add(posList PosList, docId int) {
  if ii.Len == ii.Capacity {
    newIndexList := make([]PosList, ii.Len, (ii.Capacity+1)*2)
    for i := 0; i < ii.Len; i++ {
      newIndexList[i] = make([]int, len(ii.IndexList[i]))
      copy(newIndexList[i], ii.IndexList[i])
    }
    ii.IndexList = newIndexList
  }

  ii.IndexList = ii.IndexList[0 : ii.Len+2]
  ii.IndexList[docId] = posList
  return
}
```

Or, i try something like this:

```
func (ii *InvertedIndex) Add(posList PosList, docId int) {

  if ii.Len == ii.Capacity {
    newIndexList := make([]PosList, ii.Len, (ii.Capacity+1)*2)
    copy(newIndexList, ii.IndexList)
    ii.IndexList = newIndexList
  }

  ii.IndexList = ii.IndexList[0 : ii.Len+2]
  ii.IndexList[docId] = posList
  return
}
```

Both of them don't work, may be someone can explain how can i append a slice to structure like this.

Comment: How do they not work? What error are you getting? I would note that  both versions will panic if your `docId` parameter is not within 2 of `ii.Len`; if it's guaranteed to be so you might be better off just using `append()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is confusing. I assume that you are trying to create a typical inverted index. In which case, you probably want to do something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type DocId int

type Positions []int

type docIndex struct {
    docId     DocId
    positions Positions
}

type InvertedIndex struct {
    docIndexes []docIndex
}

func New() *InvertedIndex {
    return &InvertedIndex{}
}

func (ii *InvertedIndex) Add(docId DocId, positions Positions) {
    for i, di := range (*ii).docIndexes {
        if di.docId == docId {
            di.positions = append(di.positions, positions...)
            (*ii).docIndexes[i] = di
            return
        }
    }
    di := docIndex{
        docId:     docId,
        positions: positions,
    }
    (*ii).docIndexes = append((*ii).docIndexes, di)
}

func main() {
    ii := New()
    docId := DocId(11)
    positions := Positions{42, 7}
    ii.Add(docId, positions)
    positions = Positions{21, 4}
    ii.Add(docId, positions)
    docId = DocId(22)
    positions = Positions{84, 14}
    ii.Add(docId, positions)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *ii)
}
```

Output:

```
{docIndexes:[{docId:11 positions:[42 7 21 4]} {docId:22 positions:[84 14]}]}
```

The statement:

```
di.positions = append(di.positions, positions...)
```

appends a slice to a slice.

---

References:

[Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

[inverted index](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/invertedIndex.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing, however something like this should just work fine, replacing the `slice` with a `map` :

```
type PosList []int

type InvertedIndex struct {
    Len       int
    IndexList map[int]PosList
}
func (ii *InvertedIndex) Add(posList PosList, docId int) {
    if ii.IndexList == nil {
        ii.IndexList = make(map[int]PosList)
    }
    if _, ok := ii.IndexList[docId]; ok {
        ii.IndexList[docId] = append(ii.IndexList[docId], posList...)
    } else {
        ii.IndexList[docId] = posList
    }

    ii.Len = len(ii.IndexList)
}
```